# How to create JavaScript objects to represent database entities without creating memory leak?

Tags: javascript

I have entities in a database with ID numbers.  When I load them into JavaScript as a result of queries I want to create an `Entity` object for each one.  Ideally if two entities returned from queries share the same ID then I want the JavaScript objects to be identical, e.g., `Entity({id: 42}) === Entity({id: 42})`.

I could implement this with a map that remembers currently existing Entities, indexed by ID, like this:

```
const idsToEntities = new Map();
const entity = Entity({id: 42});
idsToEntities.set(42, entity);
```

When creating another entity I can look up the ID in this map to reuse an existing object if there is one:

```
const entity = idsToEntities.get(42) || Entity({id: 42});
```

The problem with this approach is that entities will accumulate over time, creating a memory leak, because the map will prevent garbage collection.

Ideally I'd like to implement this cleverly with WeakMap somehow to avoid the memory leak but I don't see how.  Is it possible?

Comment: That's not a memory leak, that's just "using memory". Which is fine, that's the whole point of RAM, it's there to be used. Don't prematurely optimize: profile your application, and only once it turns out that map is impacting performance (actually impacting, not just "it's 20% of the app" but the entire thing's using less than a few MB of memory) start thinking about improvements.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: It’s a memory leak. The intent is just to enforce `Entity({id: 42}) === Entity({id: 42})`, not to store every entity ever queried. @DavidBraun: I don’t think this is possible automatically in JavaScript – there are no weak references. You *could* require manual deletion and do reference counting. Personally, in most cases, I’d find a way to drop the original requirement here. (Or loosen it and do an LRU cache.)

Comment: memory leaks are when data that isn't accessible anymore is held in memory instead of getting garbage collected. This is just "a map getting bigger", with the map always being accessible. They can just reset the map, or add an age to entries and periodically clear out old entries perfectly fine _once the size of their map becomes a problem_, which they should worry about once it becomes an actual problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: That’s an incorrectly narrow definition of a memory leak (consider that most allocators actually know how to reach leaked memory, for example). Resetting the map is indeed a way to solve the memory leak, but you can’t do it while an entity is live without breaking the desired guarantee. There’s also nothing wrong with being aware of and addressing a problem waiting to happen.